# How can i stop my execution flow until my API response not successfully completed?

Tags: android

Explanation:
            I am trying to explain the whole situation here. I have API call which is residing in another class (not on any activity or fragment). I am trying to call API call method using the object of that class. At that point of time I have to wait until my API response not successfully completed. On the basis of the response I need to one more API which is residing in the same class.

Problem:

I am using an AsyncHttpClient library to call the API. This is used Asynchronous methodology. If I put an API call inside activity or fragment during the calling rest of the line are trying to execute. but I want to wait until my API successfully responding me then I would like to execute a rest line of code.

Question:

What should I need to overcome from the kind of situation? I am not putting the API call inside the activity or a fragment because implementation strategy is different.

Please,help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You can use interface callback from your API class to activity, so it will hold till your API gets response

Answer (score 0):

> hii Milan, i will suggest to use https://github.com/koush/ion
>   library to your project it will be better then AsyncHttpClient
>
> i think your problem will be solved by this library.
>
> if you want the advance rest usage then use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces in this case:

1. Create an interface with methods

`onSuccess(String responseData)` 
and 
`onError(String errorData)`

2. Implement the interface in your activity or fragment. Add code which you want to execute after APIs success inside the interface's `onSuccess(String responseData)` method. Also handle `onError(String errorData)` as well.
3. While creating an object of your API class pass the implemented interface's reference to it so that API class can invoke the interface methods for the results.

Also you can use any third party libraries for this kind of work with APIs like Retrofit, volley etc.

I Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface. This way you can create your own callback whose methods can be called from onSuccess or onFailure.

```
public interface OnJSONResponseCallback {
    public void onJSONResponse(boolean success, JSONObject response);
}



public JSONObject getJSONObj(OnJSONResponseCallback callback) {
    ...
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String response) {
       try {
           jObj = new JSONObject(response);
           callback.onJSONResponse(true, jObj);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("Exception", "JSONException " + e.toString());
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable e) {
       try {
           jObj = new JSONObject(response);
           callback.onJSONResponse(false, jObj);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("Exception", "JSONException " + e.toString());
       }
   }
}
```

And to call it:

```
jsonParse.getJSONObj(new OnJSONResponseCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onJSONResponse(boolean success, JSONObject response){
       //do something with the JSON
    }
});
```